# How can i show only confirm button in bootbox prompt?

Tags: bootbox

I am using the following to create a bootbox prompt message.
(The title and the default value are obtained via an ajax request.)

```
                    bootbox.prompt({
                        title: response.message,
                        value: response.value,
                        buttons: {
                            confirm: {
                                label: 'Ok'
                            }
                        },
                        callback: function (result) {

                        }
                    });
```

Although i have setup only `confirm` button, the prompt displays also the `Cancel` Button.
What am i doing wrong here?

I have tried hiding the cancel button via css with no success like so

```
.btn btn-secondary btn-default bootbox-cancel{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: A "yes/no" dialog needs a button for each choice. If you're just showing a message to a user, that's what `bootbox.alert` (and native alerts) are for.

Comment: Unfortuanately i cannot figure out how can i show a bootbox.alert with an input field. That is why i swiched to bootbox.prompt

Comment: Any what's the reasoning behind removing the cancel button? If you really insist on having a prompt with only an OK button, you'll need to use the bootbox.dialog function to create your own custom dialog, and handle to input value manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't recommend doing this - standard user expectation for a prompt is to have an obvious way of cancelling it.

That being said... the `d-none` class, when added to the Cancel button, will hide it:

```js
bootbox.prompt({
    title: 'Please enter something:',
    callback: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    },
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            className: 'd-none'
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t3o5Lcnb/

You can't **remove** the Cancel or Confirm/OK buttons from the `bootbox.alert`, `bootbox.confirm`, or `bootbox.prompt` dialogs, but you *can* customize them (change the text, add icons, set the button classes, or add custom classes). In this case, adding the `d-none` Bootstrap class adds a `display: none;` rule to the Cancel button.

You can find a few examples of customizing the buttons on the Examples page: http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#confirm-alternate-text-color